# Qt and postgresql timezone

Tags: postgresql, qt

We have just changed timezone, and it gives me a problem with database
(I am now in the timezone GMT+2).

I have to check when something starts and I use this query :

```
SELECT *,extract(epoch from start at time zone 'cet') as start_, extract(epoch from stop at time zone 'cet') as stop_ from czas;
```

and it's wrong, because my `start_/stop_` is 1 hour older : i.e that should be 16 instead of 17 and 'cet' should be replaced by 'cest'.

I found `QTimeZone` class, which should display current short zone name (`cet/cest`), but when I use it like this :

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QTimeZone zone_;
qDebug()<<"ZONE: "<<zone_.displayName(now,QTimeZone::ShortName);
```

I get an empty string.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer why QT isn't doing what you expect.

Perhapse I can help with solving the issue you started with which is the issue of using the correct timezone?  For this PostgreSQL offers a number of timezone names which are set to the country and not the number of hours offset.  For example `'Europe/London'` specifies `'GMT'` for winter timestamps and `'BST'` for summer timestamps.

The list of these has been removed in the 9.x manual but in the 8.1 manual the list can be found here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html

For your system use the following to get a complete list of timezone names:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names;
```

I don't know which of these is most suited to your application but for example your code could be changed to:

```
SELECT *,extract(epoch from start time zone 'Europe/Paris') as start_, extract(epoch from stop at time zone 'Europe/Paris') as stop_ from czas;
```

Comment: it works!  easy change 'cet'  to 'Europe/Paris'  works!